# How to mix Generics and Abstract Types in Scala?

Tags: generics, scala, abstract-data-type

I want to do the following, but "Iterable[BASE]" won't compile. What is the right way to do it, while keeping BASE an abstract type?

```
trait Base
trait Meta {
    type BASE <: Base
}

trait EnumBase extends Base with Ordered[EnumBase]
trait EnumMeta extends Meta with Iterable[BASE] {
    override type BASE <: EnumBase
}

trait Manager extends EnumMeta {
    override type BASE <: MetaBase
}
```

I want that for every trait that extends EnumMeta and redefines BASE, that trait will be an Iterable of it's own BASE. So far I found I could instead do this:

```
trait EnumMeta extends Meta with Iterable[EnumBase] {
    override type BASE <: EnumBase
}

trait Manager extends EnumMeta with Iterable[MetaBase] {
    override type BASE <: MetaBase
}
```

Is this the only (repetitive) way, or is there a better way, as long as it doesn't require going back to the generics parameters?

[EDIT] I have just found that this will not work if the generic type parameter is the self-type, as in Ordered[EnumBase]. If you try to constrain it more in a derived class called MetaBase, you get:

```
illegal inheritance;  self-type MetaBase does not conform to
Ordered[MetaBase]'s selftype Ordered[MetaBase]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Iterable` is generic, there is a strong icentive to choose generics over type members, at least for EnumMeta and beyond. You can go from an ancestor with a type member to generics like this:

```
type EnumMeta[B <: Base] extends Meta with Iterable[B] {
  override type BASE = B
}
```

Working with several traits whose relations involves type members, you may also consider putting type member in an enclosing context rather than in the class themselves, like this

```
trait Context {
   type BASE <: Base
   type META <: Meta
   trait Base { def meta: META} 
   trait Meta { def base: BASE}
}

trait EnumContext extends Context {
   type BASE <: EnumBase
   type META <: EnumMeta
   trait EnumBase extends Base with Ordered[EnumBase] {}
    trait EnumMeta extends Meta  with Iterable[B] {}
}
```

(if at top level, traits `Base` or `Meta` are empty, remove them and just have an abstract member `type BASE` -and/or `type META`- without constraints)

When you have a context you really want to use, you can either mix it in, or make an object extending it.

```
object EnumContext extends EnumContext  {
   type BASE = EnumBase
   type META = EnumMeta
}
```

Comment: trait Base and Meta are only empty for the example; they have functionality in the real code. I have spend *days* trying to make sense of the compiler's obscure error messages concerning my generics base hierarchy, despite the fact that I have been using generics in Java since they came out, and I got a working equivalent using abstract types in less then an hour. In that light, I would only ever use again generics in Scala if there is no other way.

Comment: The example code is with Base and Meta not empty. It was just a passing note that if they were empty, they should just be removed. Maybe you could post some java equivalent of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get your code to compile is with a type projection,

```
trait Base
trait Meta {
  type BASE <: Base
}

trait EnumBase extends Base with Ordered[EnumBase]

trait EnumMeta extends Meta with Iterable[Meta#BASE] { // Type projection!
  type BASE <: EnumBase
}

trait Manager extends EnumMeta {
  // override type BASE <: MetaBase // You haven't defined type MetaBase yet
}
```

The type projection `Meta#BASE` tells the compiler which `BASE` you mean.

Unfortunately, a self reference doesn't work,

```
trait EnumMeta extends Meta with Iterable[EnumMeta#BASE] { ...
```

The compiler complains,

```
[error] illegal cyclic reference involving trait EnumMeta
[error]   trait EnumMeta extends Meta with Iterable[EnumMeta#BASE] {
[error]                                                      ^
```

This limitation is unfortunate, and is a advantage of type *parameters* over type members. See [Didierd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056878/how-to-mix-generics-and-abstract-types-in-scala/7057055#7057055) for reference.

(There's a second problem, type `MetaBase` is undefined, but that's unrelated to your question.)

Comment: OK. So you *can* reference an abstract type as generic parameter, but not your own abstract types. But then, it just suffice to introduce another in-between base trait/class that changes the abstract type, and narrow the Iterable[] with that abstract type by deriving from the in-between class again. But then, you haven't really gained anything compared to using directly the concrete type in Iterable[], like I did. At least you have a choice.